# What is the proper way of writing the first stroke of 言?

Tags: kanji, stroke-type

I am wondering why is it that 言 looks different in different fonts. In Gothic, the topmost part is just a horizontal line while in Google Search, it is a drop. I am really confused about what is really the proper way of writing this kanji.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Handwritten** *kanji* should follow the shapes of [教科書体]{きょうかしょたい} (*textbook fonts*). If you're unsure of the handwritten shape, you can utilise font previews to check what they're supposed to be. For example, [HG Kyokashotai by Ricoh](https://www.fonts.com/font/ricoh/hg-kyokashotai/hg-kyokashotai) displays the shape as

[image]

---

Handwritten shapes are different from Gothic, because they come from two separate traditions. Handwriting derives from [regular script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) brush calligraphy (楷書), while Gothic is derived from [Ming typeface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_(typefaces)) (明朝体).

The shape of「言」(*to speak*) can be traced like the following. Note that「言」was originally comprised of one or two horizontal marks in the shape of「一・二」on top of「舌」(*tongue*).

> **Series A** - Ancient inscription styles
>
> ## <kbd>Ａ１
> [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
> [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)499
> [合集30697](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=30697&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>Ａ２
> [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image]
> 伯矩鼎
> [集成2456](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2456&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>Ａ３
> [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)
> 金
> [image]
> 中山王方壺
> [集成9735](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9735&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>Ａ４
>
> [篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
> [image]
> [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
>
> **Series B** - Brush or pen writing styles
>
> ## <kbd>Ｂ１
> [楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
> [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
> [image]
> [信1](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・03</kbd>
> 　<kbd>Ｂ２
> [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
> 簡
> [image]
> [睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)・[秦](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)1</kbd>
> 　<kbd>Ｂ３
> [西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)
> 篆・[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
> [image]
> [老子](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao_Te_Ching)・甲</kbd>
> 　<kbd>Ｂ４
> [晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_dynasty_(265%E2%80%93420))・[王羲之](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Xizhi)
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]
> [蘭亭序](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchid_Pavilion_Gathering)</kbd>
> 　<kbd>Ｂ５
> 今
> 楷
> [image]
> [HG正楷書体](https://www.fonts.com/font/ricoh/hg-seikaishotai-pro)</kbd>
> 　<kbd>Ｂ６
>
> [教科書體](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script#Derivatives)
> [image]
> [HG教科書体](https://www.fonts.com/font/ricoh/hg-kyokashotai)</kbd>
>
> **Series C** - Print styles
>
> ## <kbd>Ｃ１
> [宋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_dynasty)
> [宋朝體](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imitation_Song)
> [image]
> 朱慶餘詩集</kbd>
> 　<kbd>Ｃ２
> [清](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qing_dynasty)
> [明朝體](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_(typefaces))
> [image]
> [康熙字典](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangxi_Dictionary)</kbd>
> 　<kbd>Ｃ３
> 今
> 明朝體
> [image]
> [HG明朝](https://www.fonts.com/font/ricoh/hg-mincho)</kbd>
> 　<kbd>Ｃ４
>
> [ゴシック體](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asian_Gothic_typeface)
> [image]
> [HGゴシック](https://www.fonts.com/font/ricoh/hg-gothic)</kbd>

The handwritten and print styles are both newer than the ancient inscription styles, and have shapes which originate from one of the older styles. However, they will also often develop in their own way, whilst sometimes incorporating features from an older style.

The drop in「言」has long been a brush calligraphy feature (see transition from「Ｂ３」to「Ｂ４」), and was passed on to the earliest print shape「Ｃ１」, but later print styles changed in their aesthetic qualities, and sometimes also re-incorporated features from older inscription shapes.

Comment: The 教科書体 form of 言 does look like an Ausgleichsform tho

Answer (score 3):

言's first stroke is different in handwriting and in computer code, mainly because it is more recognizeble in lower resolutions as a horizontal line.

When you are handwriting, you should draw the first stroke like shown in the picture, as a diagonal line:

[image: notice that the app recognized the kanji]

Notice that in most digital media, the word kanji(言)'s first stroke is a horizontal line

Comment: Forms with the horizontal stroke are much, much older than the invention of the computer or digital display of Chinese characters, and they are still often used when the resolution is not a limiting factor, so I don't think this can be the right explanation.

Comment: I personally think that downvoting this is a bit harsh. It answered the main question correctly, even though the reasoning was a bit off. Correct *kanji* explanations are extremely difficult to come by.